# iOS device freezes and must be rebooted when running app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I cannot run an application directly from the device. I set the provisioning with the Apple certificate and updated CFBundleIdentifier but when I tap on the application icon, the all system freeze and the device become inoperable until it reboots.

Comment: If you have two different questions, you should post it as two separate questions, not both combined into one.

Comment: Your info is vague. Did you follow the [steps for ad-hoc deployment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Ad_hoc_Distribution)? #2 should be a separate question; this is not a Qs&As (QuestionS and AnswerS) site, but a Q&A (Question and Answer) site.

Comment: DanielH, I edited your question to contain only a single question, to remove the signoff (even though it's polite to say 'Thanks', there's no need, it's assumed), and to make the question title useful. Please post your second question as a second question. Please familiarise yourself with how SO works - one question per question, clear, as much detail as possible. See this very useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Right now this question doesn't contain enough info for us to answer, either - can you add more please? For example, what version of iOS, what version of Delphi, what version of Xcode? Does it happen with a brand new empty app? Things like that last one are basic problem-solving steps that I'm sure you have already tried, but you need to communicate to us the results of those, as well as useful pertinent details, because otherwise we don't know.  (How can we? We only know what you write :)) Don't be put off - we will help if we can :)

Comment: It's possible [this XE8 hotfix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30221) might be the solution. Of course we don't know since you haven't added enough information yet.  Please update your question!

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, I'll make to sure to elaborate my next questions. I have to break my comment in chunks since I'm getting a "too long" form SO. 

As for this one, here are the details:

iOS version: 8.3
Delphi version: XE7
XCode version: 6.3 (6D570)

Meanwhile I searched more and find out the solution, the problem was with the value set in the "Mobile Prosion Profile" in the provisioning section. The title "Mobile Provision Profile" is confusing and it should be "Provision Profile File Path".

Comment: The link mentioned by Ken doesn't explain how to set the provisioning values but this one does:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Provisioning#Mobile_Provision

Ironically the field's item name on that page is mentioned as "Mobile Provison Path".

Too bad the instructions of embarcadero are so weak, ending up wasting time for something so simple.

Anyway, thank you all for your replies. Now I will put my head in drafting my next questions better :)

Comment: Does that mean you solved the problem? If so, please add an answer to this question - it's quite ok (and in fact encouraged) to answer your own questions if you find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for the field "Mobile Provision Profile" was unclear under XE7 and that was the reason it didn't work since I assumed the value stands for the certificate name rather than the FULL path of the certificate file.
As mentioned in my comment, the name of that field was renamed in XE8 to "Mobile Provison Path". Makes more sense.